# Python script updating google sheet is missing some info

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a python script that runs in the background and every hour updates a google sheet with fresh data from a SQL query. The catch being, there are two columns in the google sheet that are manually updated by business user. the python script, before refreshing the SQl data, stores those two columns and one unique id column in a dataframe and then vlookups and adds those two to the output of the refreshed SQl query.

This has been working really well but recently the sheet sometimes misses some data from the manually entered columns. I am not sure why this happens. Seeing the version history, the notes were there and then they were gone in the next auto update.

Could it be that if people are working on the file while it is being refreshed, there are errors? or does having filters/hidden column impact the way python picks up or writes the google sheet.

in a real fix. please help!

Comment: It's will be helpful if you provide the information regarding the tools which you used. Like packages, how did you run the script etc?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.